# Joomla, Is it possible to provide pagination for sub categories?

Tags: joomla

Respected Specialists,

Is it possible to provide pagination for subcategories in joomla. Its loading all subcategories in page and it is making the page to load slower.

yours faithfully
murulimadhav

Comment: Everything is possible. What's the version of Joomla, what categories are you talking about - standart Joomla's?

Comment: Respected Sir,                                                           I am trying in Joomla! 3.2.3 Stable. And I am telling about display of subcategories in "categories blog" and also in "categories-list" layout page. In these pages subcategories are shown. And if we have high number of sub categories, then we cannot paginate "subcategories". yours faithfully

Comment: So, just to be sure, you want to make double pagination. One for all articles and another for subcategories itself, right?

Comment: Respected Sir, yes Sir, double pagination. For articles its there but for subcategories there is no pagination, so its loading all the whole list of subcategories in one page. Yours faithfully

Comment: Sorry for such waiting, mate. Been in hospital lately. Unfortunately it's not possible to achieve with core component as it is. You need to develop custom plugin for this purpose. You need to be familiar with Joomla development to achieve such goal.

Comment: Respected Sir, Ya i guess i have to create a new layout model for that for blog. Let me struggle in that way. Thanking you a lot for guiding me Sir. Take care. Yours faithfully